# Do not select elements that contain data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

I have a selector that pulls in all anchor tags that start with the `#` symbol. I am trying to add a `:not` selector of some form for elements that have a `data` attribute. I know I could do the following...

```
$('a[href^="#"]:not([data-known])')
```

But the problem is that I don't know what the `data` attribute will be called. I have resorted to doing the following.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event){
    if($.isEmptyObject($(this).data())){
        //custom code here
    }
});
```

Is there a way to avoid the `if` statement and add the `:not` to the original selector? Is there a better way of doing this period?

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/RXKS8/) I have been playing in.

Comment: I think your best approach would be using [jQuery.hasData()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.hasData/) (even though you will still use an if statement).

Comment: Why is that the best approach? I'd argue against it, since it [anyhow calls `isEmptyObject` under the hood](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.hasData), but with a lot of extra code that's not needed in this case.

Comment: Because of the ease of usefulness; even though you make a good point.

Comment: Actually, `hasData` simply won't work at all. `hasData` only checks for data that has been set via `.data()`. It doesn't automatically pull in the HTML5 `data-*` attributes.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BKVb/) demonstrating my point above.

Comment: That is completely true, thank you Joseph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very good question. I'm pretty sure this can't be done within the selector.

However, instead of checking the `data` every time it's clicked, `filter` the collection before applying the event listener:

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').filter(function () {
    return $.isEmptyObject( $(this).data() );
}).click(function (event) {
    // Your code here...
});
```

---

If you don't care about IE, you can check the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset) property directly, which is *much* faster and much more reliable, since `$(this).data()` also contains any arbitrary data that might have been set (possibly by a plugin):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').filter(function () {
    return $.isEmptyObject( this.dataset );
})
```

---

If you find that you have to do this a lot, you can abstract it into a custom filter, which you can then use in your selectors:

```
jQuery.expr[':']['has-data'] = function (el) {
    return ! $.isEmptyObject( $(el).data() );
    // If you don't care about IE:
    // return ! $.isEmptyObject( el.dataset );
};
```

Then just use it throughout your code:

```
$('a[href^="#"]:not(:has-data)').click(function (event) {
    // Your code here...
});
```

Comment: This is great! This solves the main issue I was facing with it having to call `$.isEmptyObject()` on every click.